# Select result of the subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, mysql5

I am trying to select the `q1.res` which would be the result of the `FROM` subquery:

```
    (SELECT SUM(gwr.res1)/(COUNT(*)*1000) as 'res' 
     FROM process.gwr 
     WHERE started = 1 AND gwr.user2 = g.id AND gwr.loss = g.id) AS q1
```

The problem is that I am trying to select the `g.id` in the subquery but for some reason it can not access it returning the error message:

`[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'g.id' in 'where clause'`

which has no sense because the g.id (`grand.id` has the `id` column)

```
SELECT
    g.name, g.point, g.mx, q1.res
FROM
    (SELECT SUM(gwr.res1)/(COUNT(*)*1000) as 'res' 
     FROM process.gwr 
     WHERE (started = 1) AND (gwr.user2 = g.id) AND (gwr.loss = g.id)) AS q1, grand g
LEFT JOIN process.users p ON (p.id = g.owner)
WHERE
    p.name != ""
ORDER BY
    g.point DESC,
    g.mx DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: is the subquery executing ok or you're getting the same error?

Comment: @Milen Pavlov It wont execute because i am trying to use the g.id of the main query.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing ' ' from 'res' on the subquery.

```
SELECT
    g.name, g.point, g.mx, q1.res
FROM
    (SELECT SUM(gwr.res1)/(COUNT(*)*1000) as res FROM process.gwr WHERE started = 1 AND gwr.user2 = g.id AND gwr.loss = g.id) AS q1, grand g
LEFT JOIN process.users p ON (p.id = g.owner)
WHERE
    p.name != ""
ORDER BY
    g.point DESC,
    g.mx DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention what the DB object 'g' is referring to. Meaning, you need to specify that as a table (or a view) in your 'FROM' portion either as a pure cross-reference or - if you are comfortable - then using a join of some sort.

e.g

```
SELECT SUM(gwr.res1)/(COUNT(*)*1000) as 'res' 
FROM process.gwr, process.g 
WHERE started = 1 
    AND gwr.user2 = g.id 
    AND gwr.loss = g.id
```

Notice the 'process.g' in the 'FROM' portion.

Hope that helped.

K

Comment: This will select the first g.id of the `process.g`. I want it to use the `g.id` of the main query.

Comment: Right. Since you are referring the table 'grand' in the main query (outer query), you can't refer to g in the inner sub query. So, your choices are to either remove the where clause from the inside and stick in the main query where clause or to refer to the table grand as g in the inner query (and remove it from the outside).